# trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource

Tags: java

Why i keep getting this?

```
   Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.SecurityException: trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource from http://xxxx/framework/lib/simplecaptcha.jar
```

Url is deleted, but it works.

What should i do to get rid of the "Security Dialog" that comes?

Comment: Your first concern should be *why it is there*, it's not called a `SecurityException` for fun. Once you have convinced yourself that it's nothing to worry about, you can think about getting rid of it.

Comment: What are you talking about, it's a captcha libary to my game. It should be there and it's not unsafe.

Comment: Its an exception. If its coming along then you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: It may or may not be unsafe, but it's likely unsigned. See my answer below.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with code that is completely signed.  It's intermittent.  Most users are fine, but there's a couple users where it occurs at seemingly random times.  It won't happen for months, then suddenly they spew a bunch of these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has an extensive article on exactly this issue available on their website:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest

(And I guess it's fair to mention that it is the *second* google hit for "securityexception trusted loader".)

Comment: Helpful information, but not a solution in my case.  We really need to get this question re-opened and get more replies.